# Angularjs - Using $http on a HTTPS URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the $http service on a HTTPS URL with the following code :

```
var request = $http.post('https://my.custom.url/webservice', privateAttributes.requestData);
request.success(function(data, status) {

}).error(function(data, status) {
    console.log('data -', data);
    console.log('status -', status);
});
```

The my.custom.url is on a different domain as my angularJS app, but my webserver is well configured to allow cross domain XHR request. It's supposed to be a public webservice.

When the request is sent, the promise is instantly rejected, so the `error()` function is triggered. The `data` is `undefined` and the `status` is `0`.

On the network tab of my debugger in Chrome, I can see a pending OPTIONS request corresponding to my `$http.post()` call.

For testing purpose, I tried to do the same request with jQuery `$.post()` method and it worked with no issue. I think I am making something wrong with the `$http` service.

Please note that it's not a XSRF issue and if I use the HTTP version of my webservice, the request is a success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am just coming across this issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to tell it to send the cookie:

In your config, DI `$httpProvider` and then set `withCredentials` to `true`:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
```

Info on angularjs withCredentials: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Which links to the mozilla article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#section_5

Comment: It's not working. The $http call is still instantly rejected and I still have a pending OPTIONS request in the Network tab of the debugger. However, I managed to make it work by forcing the browser to bypass the OPTIONS request by setting a proper content-type and by disabling the `X-Requested-With` header : `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = undefined; $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';`